# Remote Plugins for ISF

Tags: desire2learn

I want to extend the "Insert Stuff Framework" in the D2L LMS. I understand there is a concept of  ["Remote Plugins"](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/uiplugins.html#remote-plugins) and there are [examples for "Widgets"](http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/02/15/remote-plugins-the-bookwidget-sample-2/).  Can I use Remote Plugins for ISF as well?

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2013 Remote Plugins are not (yet) available for the ISF system, but, they are available for Course Builder.  If you can fit your workflow into course builder that is the best choice *today*.  ISF is an obvious next top area to make available through remote plugins. If the project is not starting immediately check again as more remote plugins points will be appearing.